# If Statement With a Container Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a condition so that if the value is different from null I want the container with that information to appear, if the value is null I don't want to show anything but the problem is that a null text is appearing instead. What can be happening?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Column(
            children: [
            Container(
                child: ("$_info" != null)
                    ? Container(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, 
                            vertical: 35),
                        child: Text(
                          "$_info",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                 ),
               ],
              ),
             };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new String from `_info` and test if it's different from null as in

```
"$_info" != null
```

This is always going to be true, because all Strings are different from null. So you're going to see the text "null" appearing on the screen because you have `Text("$_info")` later on.

Instead, you should just test if `_info` itself is different from null. So:

```
_info != null
```